# Computing an expectation based on accuracy of future data as a random variable for a binary classifier.

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I am reading Peter Flach's introduction to machine learning and the following paragraph p.345 (top of the page) [here](http://dsd.future-lab.cn/members/2015nlp/Peter_Flach_Machine_Learning._The_Art_and_Scienc(BookZZ.org).pdf) for measuring the performance of a binary classifier.

> In machine learning the situation is usually more concrete, and our
>   experimental objective – accuracy, say – is something we can measure
>   in principle, or at least estimate (since we’re generally interested
>   in accuracy on unseen data). However, there may be unknown factors we
>   have to account for. For example, the model may need to operate in
>   different operating contexts with different class distributions. In
>   such a case we can treat accuracy on future data as a random variable
>   and take its expectation, assuming some probability distribution over
>   the proportion of positives pos. Since $acc = pos·tpr + (1 − pos)·tnr$
>   where (tpr = true positive rate, tnr = true negative rate), and
>   assuming we can measure true positive and negative rates independently
>   of the class distribution, we have (assuming a uniform distribution
>   over pos)

$\mathbb{E}[acc] = \mathbb{E} [pos·tpr +(1−pos)·tnr]
= \mathbb{E}[pos]tpr+E[1-pos]tnr = tpr/2+tnr/2$.

I do not understand this statement. What is the relationship between the proportion of positives and the random variable (the accuracy of the model)? Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what the author is saying:

- The formula $acc = pos \cdot tpr + (1 - pos) \cdot tnr$ describes how $acc$ varies as a function of $3$ parameters: $pos, tpr, tnr$.

  - The formula itself is based on the law of total probability, but that's irrelevant here.  Here's a useful example:
  - $acc = P(Test=Disease)$
  - $pos = P(Disease=1)$
  - $tpr = P(Test=1\mid Disease=1)$
  - $1-pos = P(Disease=0)$
  - $tnr = P(Test=0 \mid Disease=0)$
- The parameters $tpr = P(Test=1\mid Disease=1)$ and $tnr = P(Test=0 \mid Disease=0)$ are constants via "assuming we can measure true positive and negative rates independently of the class distribution".
- The parameter $pos = P(Disease=1)$ is unknown via "the model may need to operate in different operating contexts with different class distributions", so we model $pos$ itself as a random variable, representing "some probability distribution over the proportion of positives pos" (presumably, varying due to "different operating contexts").
- Then by linearity we have:

$$\mathbb{E}[acc] = \mathbb{E} [pos·tpr +(1−pos)·tnr]
= \mathbb{E}[pos]tpr+\mathbb{E}[1-pos]tnr $$

IMHO everything so far is non-controversial.  However, the author then made one more assumption:

- By further "assuming a uniform distribution over pos" we have $\mathbb{E}[pos] = 1/2$

  - This is because $pos \in [0,1]$ obviously, so a *uniform* $pos \in [0,1]$ will have mean $1/2$.

IMHO this last assumption might be completely unrealistic (in real life).  E.g. if positive means a person having a rare-ish disease, then it's hard to imagine a real-life scenario where $pos \sim Unif(0,1)$ is a good assumption - instead $pos$ will usually be a r.v. highly concentrated near $0$.

Hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

They are using the total law of probability,

\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[acc] &=\mathbb{E}[acc|pos]Pr(pos)+ \mathbb{E}[acc|neg]Pr(neg)\\
&=tpr\cdot \frac12 + tnr\cdot \frac12\end{align}

They assume the proportion of positive and negative data to be both $\frac12$.

If we know the data comes from the positive class, the accuracy out of that class is known as tpr. Similarly for tnr.

Comment: I interpret the author as treating $pos$ as an r.v. and assuming $pos \sim Unif(0,1)$ and hence $E[pos] = 1/2$, instead of assuming $pos = 1/2$ (which is what I think you're saying).  My answer has more details on my interpretation.